# Find out a particular value from array of Dictionary

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I have an array which contains dictionary. In each dictionary again contains array of dictionary. I want figure out all the objects which has that particular value, like India.
I tried with NSpredicate. Example Array of dictionary

```
{
 Destination : [
                {
                    plan : [
                            {
                               name : "India"
                             },
                             {
                               name : "India"
                             }
                           ]
                       },
                {
                    plan : [
                            {
                               name : "Germany"
                             },
                             {
                               name : "Germany"
                             }
                           ]
                       }
                    ]
                 }
```

For this dictionary my code is

```
NSMutableArray * destinationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [destinationArray addObject:[ResponseObject objectForKey:@"Destination"]];
            NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",@"India"];
            NSArray * filtered = [destinationArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Are you having multiple object with `ResponseObject` array or single object?

Comment: my array in my answer is equal to your `[ResponseObject objectForKey:@"Destination"]`, test my code , you will know where you wrong .

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray* container = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSMutableDictionary* d in firstArray) {
    for (NSMutableDictionary* d2 in d[@"plan"]) {
        [container addObject: [d2[@"name"] mutableCopy];
    }

}
```

i believe this will do it

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",[[[ResponseObject objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"destination"]objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

[image]

in your code, when call `[[ResponseObject objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"destination"]` here return a `NSArray` contains some `NSDictionary`. when you call `objectForKey:@"name"`, it will send you a error, are you sure you code is current?

here is my test follow your data struct, the result is current.

[image]

[image]

```
    NSArray *array = @[@{@"name" : @"zhangsan",
                     @"age" : @"10",
                     @"result": @[
                                  @{@"res":@"123l"},
                                  @{@"res":@"789l"}
                                ]
                    },
                   @{@"name" : @"lisi",
                     @"age" : @"11",
                     @"result": @[
                                  @{@"res":@"123l"},
                                  @{@"res":@"789l"}
                                ]
                    },
                   @{@"name" : @"wangwu",
                     @"age" : @"12",
                     @"result": @[
                                  @{@"res":@"123l"},
                                  @{@"res":@"789l"}
                                ]
                    }];

NSString *preStr = @"res";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[c] %@",preStr, @"123"];
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSArray *res = dict[@"result"];
    [result addObjectsFromArray:[res filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}
NSLog(@"final result == %@",result);
```